# Strict Schema Validation for JaySchema

Tags: node.js, validation, schema

I'm playing around with JaySchema (https://github.com/natesilva/jayschema) for a NodeJS application I'm building using ExpressJS.  I was wondering if anyone has created, or knows how to, create custom code that ammends the library to allow "strict" validation... By "strict", I mean that any JSON properties that aren't within the schema itself return an error state for the schema's validation.

If anyone has any insight into this, I'd love to hear from you.

Also, if anyone knows an alternative library (preferably available using NPM) that does offer this option, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of digging, I figured out the solution.

JaySchema supports JSON Schema's standards (details on JSON Schema Standards Docs found [here](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html)).  Within those standards an "additionalProperties" keyword is defined as exactly what I was looking for (more information found [here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor64)).

According to the documentation (specifically section 5.4.4.4, and an example in 5.4.4.5), if "additionalProperties" is set to the boolean false, then if properties beyond those defined in the schema are found, validation fails.

Since, as I mentioned above, JaySchema supports this JSON Schema standard, if you add "additionalProperties" at the object level to false, you'll achieve the "strict" validation I was looking for.

If you're interested, you can check out the test I have up on GitHub below:

[schema](https://github.com/sidabs/js-model-play/blob/master/model-play-jayschema/data/schemas/person.js): with "additionalProperty" set to false

[test](https://github.com/sidabs/js-model-play/blob/master/model-play-jayschema/routes/models.js): with an additional property added to cause validation failure